# Sum of all Integers between two numbers

Tags: shell-script, variable

I would like to type in two numbers and get the sum of all integers between those two numbers, inclusive.

For example:

```
./sum1 2 5
```

should yield

```
sum: 14
```

because 2+3+4+5 = 14

Here's what I have so far:

```
read num1 num2
for (( i=$num1; i<=$num2; i++))
do
now how to do what i want
done
echo "The Sum of your two number and the numbers inbetween is:$i"
```

I guess I need another variable in there to somehow be added to, but I can't seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for *"arithmetic evaluation"* in your shell documentation. For example in BASH it could be:

```
n=0
for (( i = $num1; i <= $num2; i++)); do
    (( n += i ))
done
echo $n
```

Generally, if you intend to use this often, you want to make it a function rather than a standalone script. It might be more appropriate to use `(( n = n + i ))` since the shortened `+=` operator may not available in some shells that offer arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: Thank you, i tried this solution but without brackets and didnt place a space inbetween n+= : /

Comment: Spaces are mostly irrelevant, the parentheses are the key.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a `seq` command, the brute force approach:

```
$ seq 2 5 | paste -sd + - | bc
14
```

So as a function:

```
sum() { seq "$@" | paste -sd + - | bc; }
```

The smarter approach:

```
sum() { echo "$((($1+$2)*($2-$1+1)/2))"; }
```

Or to get `bc`'s precision:

```
sum() { echo "($1+$2)*($2-$1+1)/2" | bc; }
```

The idea is that to calculate:

```
2+3+4+5
```

If you double that, you can write it:

```
 2+3+4+5
+5+4+3+2
 ───────
 7+7+7+7
```

So twice your sum (`2 * s`) is 4 (`b - a + 1`) times `7` (`a + b`).

```
2 * s = (b - a + 1) * (a + b)
```

So

```
s = (b - a + 1) * (a + b) / 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Why cycle?

```
read x y
echo $(( (y - x) * (y - x + 1) / 2 + (y - x + 1) * x ))
```

In pure shell you need to `$(( ))`

Answer (score 2):

As above guys mentioned, there is a formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression:

[image: sum formula]

See more (proof and introduction) in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).